# Prove that a transformation is canonical by using $\mathbb{M}^T\cdot \mathbb{J}\cdot \mathbb{M}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

So, I was given the following problem to solve:

> A system with two degrees of freedom is described by the following hamiltonian
>   \begin{equation}
> H=p_1^2+p_2^2+\frac{1}{2}(q_1-q_2)^2+\frac{1}{8}(q_1+q_2)^2
> \end{equation}
>   Show that the following transformation is canonical by using $\mathbb{M}^T\cdot \mathbb{J}\cdot\mathbb{M}$, where $\mathbb{M}$ is the jacobian matrix and $\mathbb{J}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{O} & \mathbb{I}\\\ -\mathbb{I} & \mathbb{O}\end{pmatrix}$, where $\mathbb{O}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with all null elements and $\mathbb{I}$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix.
>   $$q_1=\sqrt{Q_1}\cdot cos(P_1)+\sqrt{2Q_2}\cdot cos(P_2)$$
>   $$q_2=-\sqrt{Q_1}\cdot cos(P_1)+\sqrt{2Q_2}\cdot cos(P_2)$$
>   $$p_1=\sqrt{Q_1}\cdot sin(P_1)+\sqrt{Q_2/2}\cdot sin(P_2)$$
>   $$p_2=-\sqrt{Q_1}\cdot sin(P_1)+\sqrt{Q_2/2}\cdot sin(P_2)$$

Well, I've started the problem by organizing the matrix $\mathbb{M}$.
$$\mathbb{M}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial P_2} & \\\
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial P_2} & \\\
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial P_2} & \\\
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial Q_2} & 
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial P_2} & 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then I found the transpose matrix of $\mathbb{M}$
$$\mathbb{M^T}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial Q_1} & \\\
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial Q_2} & \\\
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial P_1} & \\\
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial P_2} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial P_2} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial P_2} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial P_2} & 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So
$$\mathbb{M^T}\cdot \mathbb{J}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial Q_1} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial Q_1} & \\\
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial Q_2} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial Q_2} & \\\
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial P_1} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial P_1} & \\\
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial P_2} &
\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial P_2} &
\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial P_2} &
\frac{\partial p_2}{\partial P_2} & 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &
0 &
1 &
1 & \\\
0 &
0 &
1 &
1 & \\\
-1 &
-1 &
0 &
0 & \\\
-1 &
-1 &
0 &
0 & 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
gives me a $2n\times 2n$ null matrix.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: $q_1=-q_2$ and $p_1=-p_2$??

Comment: I got that from the transformations.

Comment: But that isn't true, given the definitions of $q_i$ and $p_i$, is it?

Comment: I used the following: $$q_2=-\sqrt{Q_1}cos(P_1)+\sqrt{2Q_2}cos(P_2)=-(q_1)$$

Comment: Ops, I guess you're right. My mistake on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linear Canonical Transformation the equation $M^T\,J\,M=J$ must be fulfilled

with

$$M=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1/2\,{\frac {\cos \left( {\it P1}
 \right) }{\sqrt {{\it Q1}}}}&1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}\cos \left( {\it
P2} \right) }{\sqrt {{\it Q2}}}}&-\sqrt {{\it Q1}}\sin \left( {\it P1}
 \right) &-\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\it Q2}}\sin \left( {\it P2} \right)
\\-1/2\,{\frac {\cos \left( {\it P1} \right) }{
\sqrt {{\it Q1}}}}&1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}\cos \left( {\it P2} \right)
}{\sqrt {{\it Q2}}}}&\sqrt {{\it Q1}}\sin \left( {\it P1} \right) &-
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\it Q2}}\sin \left( {\it P2} \right)
\\1/2\,{\frac {\sin \left( {\it P1} \right) }{
\sqrt {{\it Q1}}}}&1/4\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sin \left( {\it P2} \right)
}{\sqrt {{\it Q2}}}}&\sqrt {{\it Q1}}\cos \left( {\it P1} \right) &1/2
\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\it Q2}}\cos \left( {\it P2} \right)
\\-1/2\,{\frac {\sin \left( {\it P1} \right) }{
\sqrt {{\it Q1}}}}&1/4\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sin \left( {\it P2} \right)
}{\sqrt {{\it Q2}}}}&-\sqrt {{\it Q1}}\cos \left( {\it P1} \right) &1/
2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {{\it Q2}}\cos \left( {\it P2} \right) \end {array}
 \right]
$$

and

$$J= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1
\\ -1&0&0&0\\ 0&-1&0&0\end {array}
 \right] 
$$
 you get the write answer